# How to validate iOS app source code before uploading to app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have an app developed in iOS.I have developed this app for my client.I send him code & he prepares IPA & upload to app store but i can't uplaod app to app store.Now when client uplaod app he gets error while uploading app such as missing icon,missing launch screen file size etc.Now i want to validate the code at my end so that i can be sure there will be no errors when uploading app binary to app store so is there any way by which i can validate this thing?

Thanks

Comment: You can validate your app before uploading to app store. Go through this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/ValidatingYourApp.html

Comment: You can refer this
https://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create archive.
2. You can validate the build.

[image: Screen]

Comment: Screenshots (external links in general) are a bad way to answer, stackoverflow aim to be a big search/getanswer library, and a link can be easily broken after a few months ! Take some time to type every steps

Answer (score 0):

You can archive the binary and validate with your developer account or you can import keychain and certificates of production and archive the binary and validate.